# Float Button to the right inside Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

I have a button inside a `DIV` which has `display: flex` in styles.

I am using `float: right` to align the button to the right inside the `DIV` but it doesn't.

However if I add some text before the button than the button is aligned to the right.

Why? What am I missing?

```css
div {
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
} 
    
button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Save</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: if you add some text you will trigger `justify-content: space-between;` and in both cases float is doing nohing

Comment: @DCR we don't adjust snippet to answer the question inside the question.